# Doctrine2 Nested Set rendering as a table with indentation

Tags: doctrine-orm, nested-sets, doctrine-extensions

I have categories structure (using Gedmo Nested Tree extension for Doctrine2) like in the example:
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md#tree-entity-example

The question is how to display all the tree as a table like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Category-1 name</td>
      <td>Category-1 other data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Category-2 name</td>
      <td>Category-2 other data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><span class="indent">---</span>Subcategory-2-1 name</td>
      <td>Subcategory-2-1 other data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><span class="indent">---</span><span class="indent">---</span>Subcategory-2-1-1 name</td>
      <td>Subcategory-2-1-1 other data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Category-3 name</td>
      <td>Category-3 other data</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Another words, I need to get the tree as a plain list with Level param in 1 query.
I found a way to get the list only as array (getNodesHierarchy), but I need to have it as a collection like if I called findAll()

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
class CategoryRepository extends NestedTreeRepository
{
    public function getTreeList()
    {
        return $this->getNodesHierarchyQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```